# Does the statements in the Finally block still execute in this piece of code ?

Tags: delphi, try-finally

Will finally block execute? if I pass exit; ?

```
procedure someProc;
begin
    Try
      Exit;
    finally
     do_something;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Side note: `while True do
 try
  Exit;
 finally
  Continue;
 end;` will not compile - see [Fun with Infinite Loops in Delphi and Java](http://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/fun-with-infinite-loops-in-delphi-and-java/)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, `finally` blocks always execute, even if you call `Exit` somewhere. They wouldn't be worth much if they weren't *always* executed.

Answer (score 30):

The finally clause will always be executed, unless the executing thread enters a non-terminating loop, blocks indefinitely or is terminated abnormally, whilst executing the try clause.

The pertinent [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions#Try...finally_Statements) states (emphasis mine):

> The syntax of a try...finally statement is
>
> ```
> try 
>   statementList1
> finally
>   statementList2 
> end
> ```
>
> where each statementList is a sequence of statements
>   delimited by semicolons.
>
> The try...finally statement executes
>   the statements in statementList1 (the try clause). If statementList1 finishes without raising exceptions,
>   statementList2 (the finally clause) is executed. If an exception is raised during execution of statementList1,
>   control is transferred to statementList2; once statementList2
>   finishes executing, the exception is re-raised. **If a call to the
>   Exit, Break, or Continue procedure causes control to leave
>   statementList1, statementList2 is automatically executed.**
>   Thus the finally clause is always executed, regardless of how the try clause terminates.

Comment: +1 for listing those conditions when the finally clause is not executed.

Comment: @MrLister No I did not. Read again the first paragraph.

Comment: Don't forget on power outage, natural catastrophes and possible alien attacks :-)

Comment: @TLama I didn't. They are covered by the catch all "terminated abnormally"! ;-)

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed that. Well, that should cover also falling piano accidents.

Comment: This is the part I was looking for: *once statementList2 finishes executing, **the exception is re-raised.***

Answer (score 15):

A quick test app could have answered this question really quickly.

```
program TestFinally;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

begin
  try
    WriteLn('Before exiting');
    Exit;
  finally
    WriteLine('In finally. If you see this, it was written after "Exit" was called');
    ReadLn;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 12):

For the sake of completeness - finally block will **not** execute if the process or thread executing the try..finally block is terminated with TerminateProcess/TerminateThread.

For example, finally block will not be executed in the code below.

```
o := TObject.Create;
try
  TerminateThread(GetCurrentThread, 0);
finally
  o.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Did I miss that in my answer? Maybe I should have said terminate *thread* abnormally rather than program.

Comment: You're right, you said that. Feel free to merge my example in your answer, then I'll delete mine.

Comment: I edited my text to make it a little more complete. Your answer covers that particular aspect in depth and I think merging your example into my answer would detract from the main point which is the documentation quote. Thanks and +1.